# Duplicate rows in MYSQL result LEFT JOIN UNION RIGHT JOIN (FULL JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I have a little complex query that I want to do full join of. I am in a process of migrating my database from SQL Server to MYSQL and am stuck at converting this SQL Query. Any help would be highly appreciated. Here is the actual SQL Server query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        tac.Name as 'Category',
        SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
        SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
        SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
        SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
            d.TestCaseId,
            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
        JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
        JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
        WHERE
            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
    ) a
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
            d.TestCaseId,
            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
        JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
        JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
        WHERE
            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
            d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
    ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId AND a.TestAreaCategoryId = b.TestAreaCategoryId)
    JOIN TestAreaCategories tac ON (a.TestAreaCategoryId = tac.Id)
    GROUP BY tac.Name
    UNION
    SELECT
        'Any Category' as 'Category',
        SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
        SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
        SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
        SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
    FROM (
        SELECT
            d.TestCaseId,
            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
        WHERE
            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
    ) a
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT
            d.TestCaseId,
            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
        WHERE
            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
            d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
    ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId)
) r
ORDER BY
    r.ConsistentlyFailingToday DESC,
    r.StartedFailingToday DESC,
    r.ConsistentlyFailingYesterday DESC,
    r.StartedFailingYesterday DESC
```

I have tried this but I am having duplicate rows:

```
DECLARE @TodayDate DATE = GETDATE() - 39, @YesterdayDate DATE = GETDATE() - 40, @BranchId INT = 56;
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT
                    tac.Name as 'Category',
                    SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
                    SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
                    SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
                    SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
                FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
                            d.TestCaseId,
                            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                        JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
                        JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
                        WHERE
                            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
                            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                    ) a
                LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
                                d.TestCaseId,
                                d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                                d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                            FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                            JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
                            JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
                            WHERE
                                d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                                d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
                                (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                        ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId AND a.TestAreaCategoryId = b.TestAreaCategoryId)
                JOIN TestAreaCategories tac ON (a.TestAreaCategoryId = tac.Id)
                GROUP BY tac.Name
                UNION
                SELECT
                    tac.Name as 'Category',
                    SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
                    SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
                    SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
                    SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
                FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                            ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
                            d.TestCaseId,
                            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                        JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
                        JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
                        WHERE
                            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
                            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                    ) a
                RIGHT JOIN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                ta.TestAreaCategoryId,
                                d.TestCaseId,
                                d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                                d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                            FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                            JOIN TestAreaTestCases tatc ON (tatc.TestCase_Id = d.TestCaseId)
                            JOIN TestAreas ta ON (tatc.TestArea_Id = ta.Id)
                            WHERE
                                d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                                d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
                                (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                        ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId AND a.TestAreaCategoryId = b.TestAreaCategoryId)
                JOIN TestAreaCategories tac ON (a.TestAreaCategoryId = tac.Id)
                GROUP BY tac.Name
                UNION
                SELECT
                    'Any Category' as 'Category',
                    SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
                    SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
                    SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
                    SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
                FROM (
                        SELECT
                            d.TestCaseId,
                            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                        WHERE
                            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
                            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                    ) a
                LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT
                                d.TestCaseId,
                                d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                                d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                            FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                            WHERE
                                d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                                d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
                                (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                        ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId)
                        UNION
                        SELECT
                    'Any Category' as 'Category',
                    SUM(a.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingToday',
                    SUM(a.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingToday',
                    SUM(b.AlwaysFailingCount) as 'ConsistentlyFailingYesterday',
                    SUM(b.StartedFailing) as 'StartedFailingYesterday'
                FROM (
                        SELECT
                            d.TestCaseId,
                            d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                            d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                        FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                        WHERE
                            d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                            d.CachedDate = @TodayDate AND
                            (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                    ) a
                RIGHT JOIN (
                            SELECT
                                d.TestCaseId,
                                d.AlwaysFailingCount,
                                d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount as 'StartedFailing'
                            FROM DailyScenarioResults d
                            WHERE
                                d.BranchId = @BranchId AND
                                d.CachedDate = @YesterdayDate AND
                                (d.AlwaysFailingCount != 0 OR (d.PassedNowFailedCount - d.FailedLastTestCount) != 0)
                        ) b ON (a.TestCaseId = b.TestCaseId)
            ) r
ORDER BY
    r.ConsistentlyFailingToday DESC,
    r.StartedFailingToday DESC,
    r.ConsistentlyFailingYesterday DESC,
    r.StartedFailingYesterday DESC
```

I am having this result:

[image: Result Screenshot]

This is the actual result I am hoping to get:

[Actual Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4npSc.png)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT *` to remove duplicates.

Comment: They don't match because the startedfailingtoday is different so distinct wont help...union already removes dups

Comment: @Barmar `SELECT DISTINCT *` wont work as the data is already distinct. Have already tried that.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I know. Any idea on how to get the full join on this then??
Would be highly appreciated. I have tried but not that much of work.

Comment: Now I see, they're not really duplicates. How are the rows with the same `Category` supposed to be combined?

Comment: Which of the two records do you want and why...that's unclear

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I have edited the question with the screenshot of the actual result I want (at the bottom). [Screenshot taken from SQL Server Management Studio as full join works in SQL but not in MYSQL]

Comment: For now, what I have done is at the very first SELECT, I have done `SELECT r.Category, MAX(r.ConsistentlyFailingToday), MAX(r.StartedFailingToday), MAX(r.ConsistentlyFailingYesterday), MAX(r.StartedFailingYesterday) FROM` and at bottom have deleted ORDER BY code and instead added `GROUP BY r.Category` which is giving me the desired result for some dates but not sure if it is the correct way or not. Also, this query is taking a lot of time to run. Any better suggestions??

Comment: You could do distinct with the greatest function assume they have that inmysql...the greatest of 2 columns

Comment: I got this working @Ctznkane525 using select MAX but the query is really really slow. I need to look into a work around to make it run faster.